# Get a document with only sub documents matching a criteria with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, subdocument

I have this mongoose model:

```
var mySubEntitySchema = new Schema({
  property1: String,
  property2: String
});

var myEntitySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  sub: [mySubEntitySchema]
});

export var MyEntityModel: mongoose.Model<MyEntityDocument> = mongoose.model<MyEntityDocument>("MyEntity", myEntitySchema);
```

Now I want to get a specific MyEntityDocument for which I have the _id, but only with the subDocuments matching property1 = "example".

Is there any way to do that?

I tried a solution using Aggregate but without any success:

```
MyEntityModel.aggregate([
{$match: { "_id": myId, "sub.property1":"example" }},
      {$unwind: "$sub"},
      {$match: { "sub.property1":"example"}},
      {$group: {"_id":"$_id","subs":{$push:"$sub"}}}
    ], (error, result) => {
        console.log("Result = " + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    });
```

But it returns nothing. If I don't put "_id": myId in the first $match clause, then I get results, but I only want the one result that corresponds to the _id I have.

Anyone knows how I can do this?

EDIT: As asked, here is an example.

With this data:

```
  {
    "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e4",
    "name": "a",
    "sub": [
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e0",
        "property1": "example",
        "property2": "something"
      },
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e1",
        "property1": "notmuch",
        "property2": "somethingelse"
      },
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e2",
        "property1": "notinteresting",
        "property2": "something"
      },
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e3",
        "property1": "example",
        "property2": "anotherthing"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "54c12277fcb2488d300795e5",
    "name": "b",
    "sub": [
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e6",
        "property1": "example",
        "property2": "word"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want the entity with _id "54c12276fcb2488d300795e4" and the subdocs that match property1 = "example". So the expected result is:

```
  {
    "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e4",
    "name": "a",
    "sub": [
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e0",
        "property1": "example",
        "property2": "something"
      },
      {
        "_id": "54c12276fcb2488d300795e3",
        "property1": "example",
        "property2": "anotherthing"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample data set and the result you want over here??

Comment: @AnanthPai 
Just edited to add a sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findOne` to retrieve what you want.

```
MyEntityModel.findOne({_id : myId , "sub.property1" :"example"},{'sub.$' : 1},function(err,result){
    if(!err)
    {
        if(result)
        {
            //result is the document you were searching for
        }
    }
});
```

> {'sub.$' : 1} will return only the matched element.

Go through [mongoose query documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be working fine and as expected to get the result, except the syntax of the aggregate function is improper. Refer [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) link on how aggregate queries are written using mongoose. You shouldn't be passing an array as you would in `mongodb console`. Just pass the queries separated by commas as shown in the query below.

```
MyEntityModel.aggregate(
  {$match: { "_id": myId, "sub.property1":"example" }},
  {$unwind: "$sub"},
  {$match: { "sub.property1":"example"}},
  {$group: {"_id":"$_id","name": {"$first": "$name"}, "subs":{$push:"$sub"}}}
, (error, result) => {
    console.log("Result = " + JSON.stringify(result));
  }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, I have no idea why. If I don't put the match on _id it just works fine, but as soon as I add this criteria, the result is empty.
Well in my real code I don't exactly match on _id but on another property, don't know if it makes things different?

Comment: can you share the value of `myId` before its passed to the aggregate function, in a `console.log`

Comment: I simplified my code so that it would be easier to understand, so I don't really have a myId value. But anyway my criteria is good, because things go like that:

A findOne with "_id": myId gives back a result.
The aggregate without "_id": myId gives back all documents with the subdocuments matching sub.property1: "example" (and only those subdocuments)
As soon as I add the "_id": myId to the aggregate, I suddenly get no result.